# Basics on group operation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let's $G$ be a group and $H \le G$. $H$ brings a partition of $G$, $\lambda_H(G)=(H,\complement_GH$), where $\complement_GH:=G \setminus H$. Firstly, I notice that, as $g \in G \Leftrightarrow g^{-1} \in G$, then also $g \in \complement_GH \Leftrightarrow g^{-1} \in \complement_GH$.

Now, I claim that $g \in H, g' \in \complement_GH \Rightarrow gg' \in \complement_GH$. In fact, $gg' \in H \Rightarrow g'=g^{-1}(gg') \in H$: contradiction. Then, $gg' \in \complement_GH$.

So, denoted by $f \colon G \times G \rightarrow G$ the group operation, we get:

- $f(G \times G) \subseteq G$
- $f(H \times H) \subseteq H$
- $f(H \times \complement_GH) \subseteq \complement_GH$
- $f(\complement_GH \times H) \subseteq \complement_GH$

Finally, I claim that $f(\complement_GH \times \complement_GH) \cap H \ne \emptyset$. In fact, differently, we'd have that $f(\complement_GH \times \complement_GH) \subseteq \complement_GH$ and then $\complement_GH \le G$: contradiction, because $e \notin \complement_GH$.

Is this whole correct?

Comment: Yes, this all looks fine, though it is somewhat more complicated than it needs to be. $G$ is the union of cosets of $H$ and acts on these with $H$ being the stabilizer of itself, so $H$ acts on the remaining cosets, which is your complement.

Comment: Thank you Tobias. I'll come back to your comment when I'll be more acquainted with concepts of higher-level than current mine, like action, stabilizer, etc.

Answer (score -1):

It is not really clear what you are asking about. Though, your reasoning is correct.

But, note that, you cannot say that $H$ partitions the group $G$. It would be saying that it is **a set's property** to partition any other sets/groups/categories etc. in which it is included. You see, *having a complement* is not what we call **partitioning,** even if it seems similar. With complements, it is already too trivial! For example, you could omit all your proof between second line and the before last one: As $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, thus the identity element of $G$ is included in $H$, thus no way it can be for the complement of $H$; so that we conclude **the complement can never be a subgroup of $G$.**

But the properties you showed would still remain valid.

Except that:

1. When you tried to proceed by contradiction at the last line, you began with a **logically false** claim. The proof holds on itself. But it is not how it is done. We *prefer(!)* beginning with a **logically valid** statement which doesn't hold with the given propositional phrase, *then* we try to arrive either to a **logically false** conclusion or **any conclusion which does not hold with predicate** to prove a contradiction.
2. I surely think that $ f( \bar{H} \times \bar{H}) \subseteq \bar{H} $ cannot imply that $\bar{H}$ is a subgroup of $G$ too. (where $\bar{H}$ is the complement). It only shows an inclusion; and nothing about a property at all.

Comment: My aim was to prove that $f(\complement_GH \times \complement_GH) \subseteq \complement_GH$ is false; along the proof, I used the fact that $\complement_GH$ is not a subgroup of $G$, as can be straightforwardly obtained as you said. Since I have pretty no basis in logics, I'd really appreaciate a logically flawless version of my proof. Thanks

Comment: Well, and actually -given an $H \le G$- I wished to make an "inventory" of $f(\dots \times \dots)$ in terms of $H$ and $\complement_GH$

Comment: You should, on this forum, mention explicitly your goal. Otherwise the answers tend to vary. Said you that you wanted a detailed "logical argumentation" as if exercise, I'd do it already.

Answer (score -1):

The inclusion relation is what we call an *ordering.* It is, in fact, a linear ordering in this case. **A linear ordering** is a partial ordering in which the comparaison quality is well defined for every element pairwise distinct. Now, I will initiate you to a higher theorem:

*("higher" in the sense that, here, we don't make use of it within its usual definition for limits; but for a different metric, ie. topological space with different ordering, but which holds well because they are isomorphic, ie. homoemorphic.)*

So, you can use here **the Sandwich Theorem.** You see, the image of complements is ordered **by usual set inclusion** between the complement of $G$ and the $H$ itself. Though we know that we cannot have any element outside $G$. But we cannot have any in $H$ neither: Otherwise we would have images of $H$ and its complement intertwining. And as $f$ is a homomorphism of groups, it cannot be, thus contradiction.

You see, with the reasoning I told above, adapting it to different cases is only up to your redaction and comprehension. It becomes free of your choice for underlying set (ie. $Dom(f)$ here). You just need: 1. the linear ordering of inclusion (which you surely have here -unless in higher mathematics), 2. the function $f$ to be homomorphism of groups.

Comment: I have a very hard time following this answer. For example, $f$ is certainly not going to be a group homomorphism in most cases.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft the trouble with your comprehension is the same reason I **supposed** $f$ homomorphic here. You are right to say not every $f$ is a morphism, but we have a stranger case here: **$f$ is the internal law.** So in fact, the question would be nothing but empty as it is. Luca , can you review your question? if $f$ is a function defined on $(G,\times)$ than we have interest in the case only when it is homomorphism. otherwise no conclusion.

Comment: The $f$ defined in the question is completely fine and makes sense. It defines an action of $G$ on itself. The fact that it will only be a homomorphism when the group is abelian is irrelevant to the actual question.

Comment: who said about abelian? My reasoning holds for $G$ monoid

Comment: I have no idea what your "reasoning" is. The map $f$ in question is a homomorphism iff $G$ is abelian, and you seemed to take it for granted that it was a homomorphism.

Comment: then you show it to conclude, at the end, that $f(\complement_{G}H \times \complement_{G}H) \subseteq \complement_{G}H$ so that we all know.